# Sad Face in lieu of Map loading?

Tags: here-api

Getting reports from visitors that they are seeing a sad face load instead of the maps.  Using the latest API.

Has anybody ever seen this or know the reason why it would show up?

Comment: Which API is being used ? Are you hitting Production Environment or CIT environment ?

Comment: It's a prod environment using the latest v3 API.

Comment: Are there any error in the browser console ? In general the API will return with an error code if there are issues.

Comment: Not sure about browser errors.  I can't recreate the issue.  It was reported by a customer.  No screenshots. Can't recreate.  I've never experienced a sad face myself, in lue of the map loading.  I'll just write this off as some sort of browser based friendly javascript error I guess.  Seems like nobody else knows about it either.  Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 0):

We can be sure that our JS API 3.x works properly in all modern browsers and operation systems.

You can't reproduce the issue because it seems your visitors have some own issues on their side related to network, operation system, version of browsers, 32-bit browser installed on 64-bit OS, blocked map content by installed browser's extensions and etc. and etc. Because is not possible to list all potential issues would be better that visitors search the issue on his side e.g. search in internet "browsers can't load websites" or "my browser crashing"